# Can Redgate SQL Data Compare be Automated?

Tags: redgate, red-gate-data-compare

I am using Redgate Version 10. I want to have the source control in place for one of the database tables.

So, whenever I modify the data in the source control and run the automated script, It should update the database with the source control change. Is it possible with the sql data compare command line utility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your post!

Yes it is possible to use SQL Data Compare 10 command-line to compare source control with your database.

We have [an article](https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SDC10/Deploying+a+database+from+source+control) which can help you in this situation.

Please let me know if this helps or if you have any further questions.

Anu, Redgate Support Team